# How can I update the DataTemplate of a DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

Im my viewmodel I have a list of my custom objects of type `IPC.Device` bound to a property defined as

```
private ObservableCollection<IPC.Device> _devices;

public ObservableCollection<IPC.Device> Devices
{
    get
    {
        return _devices;
    }

    set
    {
        _devices = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent ("Devices");
    }
}
```

I use the ObservableCollection to populate a DataGrid, that I create with the following XAML (unnecessary parts are not shown)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MainGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Devices}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ....
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Resources.device_status},
                                                 Converter={StaticResource CapitalizeFirstLetterConverter}}"
                                Width="*" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=deviceStatus, Converter={StaticResource DeviceStatusToStringConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        ....
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Views:CameraLoginControl  Visibility="{Binding Path=deviceStatus, Converter={StaticResource DeviceStatusUnauthorizedConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Views:TestSelectionControl Visibility="{Binding Path=deviceStatus, Converter={StaticResource DeviceStatusOnlineConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

When I update the ObservableCollection byt replacing an item with its updated copy I can see that the Datagrid is correctly updated, the row is updated and the `DeviceStatusToStringConverter` is fired. Unfortunately, the `DeviceStatusUnauthorizedConverter` and `DeviceStatusOnlineConverter` are never fired again, so the RowDetailsTemplate is still the one of the previous item.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

The `IPC.Device` is, stripped of unnecessary fields:

```
public class Device
{
    [DataMember]
    public DeviceStatus deviceStatus { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

You see `[DataMember]` beacsue I use this structure in many places, also for IPC. I have other Propertied marked `[DataMember]`, thus I would exclude this as the reason why this happens. `DeviceStatus` is an enum.

Comment: Can you post your model code for IPC.Device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities to do it.

- You can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the
  `Device.deviceStatus`, then you don't need to replace an object in
  `ObservableCollection`, just modify the property.
- You can replace the whole `ObservableCollection` `Devices = new
  ObservableCollection...`
- You can remove and insert an element:
  `Devices.RemoveAt(i);`
  `Devices.Insert(i, new Device());`

Comment: I'd like to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for Device.deviceStatus, but I don't know how to do it. Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: @OttavioCampana [What's the best way to call INotifyPropertyChanged's PropertyChanged event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488587/whats-the-best-way-to-call-inotifypropertychangeds-propertychanged-event?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Eventually the RemoveAt + Insert solution was the best one.